# I am interested in disproving some graph theory conjectures in python, what is the most efficient library/server set up to use?

Tags: python, algorithm, hadoop, graph-theory, distributed-computing

I am interested in implementing and running some heavy graph-theory algorithms for the purpose of (hopefully) finding counterexamples for some conjecture.

What is the most efficient libraries, server setups you would recommend?

I am thinking of using Python's Graph API.

For running the algorithms I was thinking of using Hadoop, but researching Hadoop I get the feeling it is more appropriate for analysing databases than enumerating problems.

If my thinking about Hadoop is correct, what is the best server setup you would recommend for running such a process?

Any leads on how to run an algorithm in a remote distributed environment that won't require a lot of code rewritting or cost a lot of money would be helpful.

many thanks!

Comment: What is the size of the cluster? Hadoop might be an overkill if you are planning to run it on a single machine [though some might disagree with me]

Comment: Why Python? You sure that this is the right language for the job?

Comment: Also, mapreduce [which is the paradigm hadoop implements] is perfectly adapted to be used on graphs for certain purposes. There is also an example how reverse web-link graph in the [cannonical paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/iw//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf)

Comment: Indeed Python isn't the most efficient for this purpose, the main reason I am using it is that is the language I know best.

Comment: @amit ever heard of Google Pregel and Apache Hama or Giraph? I bet not, otherwise you'd know that MapReduce totally sucks for graph algorithms. Building an inverted index is not a graph problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can look CUDA as another option, if it is highly computational task.

Answer (score 1):

You  could have a look on [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) which is a no-sql graph database. If your scalability constraints are strong, it could be a good choice.

Interface is REST based, but some python bindings exist too (see [here](https://github.com/neo4j/python-embedded))

You can have a look here for a [blog](http://markorodriguez.com/technology/) with some graph theory applications ( a small study on scalability could be found [here](http://markorodriguez.com/2011/02/18/mysql-vs-neo4j-on-a-large-scale-graph-traversal/) ).

Comment: Looks interesting will look them up. Thanks. However I would like to point out that the majority of computing in my application would be spent enumerating graphs rather than having graphs stored in a database already and accessing them. I am wondering whether that would make using no-sql or any other database necessary or useful.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure it would fit your needs ... Although, there is a dedicated query language for graph enumeration (traversal). It is called Cypher(http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.4/cypher-query-lang.html ). Perhaps it could be enough for a first try ...